# Using $().trigger() and getting a TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code to trigger the event:

```
$("div.condition.editmode").trigger('removeEdit');
```

My html:

```
<div class="condition editmode"></div>
```

The console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply' jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
b.event.add.v.handle jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
b.event.trigger jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
(anonymous function) jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
b.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
b.fn.b.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
b.fn.extend.trigger
```

Comment: Well what is listening for the event *removeEdit*? That is probably where you need to look. This is probably impossible to answer without seeing that code.

Comment: Do you have a custom event `removeEdit`?

Comment: I'm listening for the event in a Backbone.js View with this:

    `this.$el.on('removeEdit',this.toggleEdit, this);`

Comment: @JonathanWill: I don't know Backbone.js, but are you sure that `.on()` syntax is correct?

Comment: @epascarello Does the DOM element need to be listening for the event or else the error will occur? There are a few of these divs that have the listener bound, but one that does not. Would that be a problem?

Comment: syntax for on definitely looks a bit odd... nothing should come after the callback.

Comment: The syntax is to pass a context to the callback function. (http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) It works elsewhere in my code. Can this js error come because of code within the callback?

Comment: @JonathanWill you probably has different this in callback from what you thinking it to be.

Comment: What is toggleEdit? Edit your post above with that code.

Comment: I guess toggleEdit is function on some object but not on window object, which is this in the callback @JonathanWill told us about.

Comment: I thought I was using the Backbone.on() on `this.$el`, but it is just a DOM element so it was actually calling jquery .on(). Therefore the on() was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is toggleEdit a function? It seems to me that jQuery is trying to do `this.toggleEdit.apply(this, arguments)` but if toggleEdit is not a function the error you would get is the one you are getting. Perhaps with more code I could be more specific

EDIT: to check that you are actually passing a function, try doing `typeof this.toggleEdit` and see what it returns. It should return "function"

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I was trying to use the Backbone.on() on this.$el which is just a DOM element. So, the on() was syntactically incorrect in this spot. Thanks everyone!

Comment: And the selected answer has nothing to do with the problem... :) Just a note if someone shows up to this answer in the future.